# Changing attribute length of existing field afterwards?

Tags: qgis, table, length

I already have about 100 values in a field in **QGIS**. I set it to 50 characters because I was thinking that would be enough. But that was wrong. I **need more space** in the column. But there is no way to change it. In the usual editor you only can remove or add a new field.

And in the "advanced" **table manager** you can change the position and rename it. But nowhere where I **edit** the **length** of a **field**.

The only thing I could do is creating a new field with more space. Then import the data somehow. But does that work somehow? Or is there a way to edit the text length afterwards. I'm also interested in hacks.

And yes I really need that. There is no way to get the string any shorter. I think 100 chars are fine.

---

Now it came to mind the following. Could maybe someone tell if that is working before I try that. So First of all I would create a new field with 100 chars column. Than select all old features and CTRL-X them and CTRL-V into the new shape.

Will that work out?

Comment: Please include the data format in data questions; it's trivial to increase the width of database tables and impossible with shapefiles.

Comment: I don't think any data example are needed here. The question is straightforward. But thanks for the info that it's impossible on shapefiles. I now just created a new column and copy pasted by hand. 2 Minutes =)

Comment: Not data *sample*, data **format**, since the options change by format. There may also be a maximum width per row (4kb for dBase < 50*100)

Answer (score 1):

The field calculator lets you easily create new fields and insert all values of an existing field in one step.

With the table manager plugin, you can delete the old field, and rename the new one to the name of the deleted field. This will work for shapefiles, but not for spatialite and postgis database tables. You have to use SQL statements for those.

Comment: Is there anywhere an tutorial that shows that scenario?

Comment: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_attributes.html might be a start-off. Just try it out on a copy of your datasource.

Comment: Well that did not work for me. But I have now done the following. Create new column and copy paste all the text into the new column. I think this was the fastest and easiest way. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I wonder why the field calculator did not work for you.